Error: No database connection string was provided to `neon()`. Perhaps an environment variable has not been set?
After adding a new Row on my database, started to get this error, been working on this project for a month, it doesn't make any sense.
Error: No database connection string was provided to neon(). Perhaps an environment variable has not been set?
Source
db\drizzle.ts (5:18) @ process
3 | import * as schema from "./schema";
4 |

5 | const sql = neon(process.env.DATABASE_URL!);
|                  ^
6 | const db = drizzle(sql, {schema});
7 |
8 | export default db;

But its all been set on my .env file
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://neondb_owner:************************/neondb?sslmode=require"
Already tried to create .env file again

Make sure to include "use server" at the top of your files accessing your db instance.
Had the same issue in an actions file because I forgot to add it.

Change the name in the .env from DATABASE_URL to NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE_URL=[your key].And use it as such in the line
 const sql = neon(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE_URL)

THIS IS THE LINK TO THE DOCS
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables]
Text from the doc:

Non-NEXT_PUBLIC_ environment variables are only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they aren't accessible to the browser
(the client runs in a different environment).
In order to make the value of an environment variable accessible in
the browser, Next.js can "inline" a value, at build time, into the js
bundle that is delivered to the client, replacing all references to
process.env.[variable] with a hard-coded value.
To tell it to do this,
you just have to prefix the variable with NEXT_PUBLIC_.
For example:

Terminal
>
> NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID=abcdefghijk

This will tell Next.js to replace all references to process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID in the Node.js environment with the value from the environment in which you run next build, allowing you to use it anywhere in your code. It will be inlined into any JavaScript sent to the browser.

in the folder in which you are initializing the db, for example dbConfig.jsx,
just use "use server" and you're good to go!
for example :


 "use server"
 import {neon} from '@neondatabase/serverless'
 import {drizzle} from 'drizzle-orm/neon-http'
 import * as schema from './schema'

 const sql = neon(process.env.DATABASE_URL)
 export const db = drizzle(sql,{schema})



